# CSS html images not stacking across

Tags: html, css, image

I am working on a course on CSS from Udemy called "Build Responsive Real World Websites with HTML5 and CSS3"

The images are supposed to stack across, like this:

```
image1   image2   image3  image 4.
```

But they are stacking down, like this:

```
image1
image2
image3
image4
```

The code is copied exactly, word for word.

Did I make a typing error?

To try and isolate the problem, I extracted the nonfunctional code into a separate file. I also tried to add

```
figure {
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
```

But that didn't work either. However this is not a part of the code that the instructor had given.

I would like to see the instructor-given code working, since ideally, I want to keep following along the same code as he gave to continue the book, so I am hoping there is maybe a syntactical issue or something, but I just can't figure it out....

Here is the code I extracted:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.meals-showcase {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.meals-showcase li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.meal-photo {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.meal-photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-meals">

  <ul class="meals-showcase">
    <li>
      <figure class="meal-photo">
        <img src="resources/img/1.jpg" alt="Korean bimimbap with egg and vegetables">

      </figure>
      <figure class="meal-photo">

        <img src="resources/img/2.jpg" alt="Chinese sholik with egg and vegetables">

      </figure>
      <figure class="meal-photo">
        <img src="resources/img/3.jpg" alt="Indian Hamachaji with">

      </figure>
      <figure class="meal-photo">
        <img src="resources/img/4.jpg" alt="Korean goolash with egg">
      </figure>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: i only put one li for this question, but there are more...

Comment: as commented earlier, if a single li, make the figure float instead : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RwbBMNM , if each are wrapped in li, it should work. if it doesn't, there must some other css else where overwriting your rules. The code you share do not seem to reproduce your issue, it is not  possible to help you from what you shared .You say you have more lis, okay , but each with four figure, or one figure per li. You should clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with every `figure` tag inside `li` tag I think that what are you trying:

```
<section class="section-meals">

        <ul class="meals-showcase">
            <li>
                <figure class="meal-photo">
                    <img src="resources/img/1.jpg" alt="Korean bimimbap with egg and vegetables">

                </figure>
            </li>

            <li>
                <figure class="meal-photo">

                    <img src="resources/img/2.jpg" alt="Chinese sholik with egg and vegetables">

                </figure>
            </li>                  

            <li>
                <figure class="meal-photo">
                    <img src="resources/img/3.jpg" alt="Indian Hamachaji with">

                </figure>
            </li>

            <li>
                <figure class="meal-photo">
                    <img src="resources/img/4.jpg" alt="Korean goolash with egg">                                       
                </figure>
            </li>
        </ul>




    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the size of your photos. I see that your code has 100% width for some of the photos. If that doesn't work, try using float:top; instead of float:left;.

Comment: Try removing your ul and li tags.

Comment: Also, instead of using the figure tag, try using the div tags.

Answer (score 0):

`.meal-photo` has a width of 100% so no images will display aside of it if you remove that and replace it with `display: inline-block;` it should work however your other problem is `.meals-showcase` li width is 25%. remove that then your images will display next to each other horizontally.

**NOTE:** Figure and DIV elements are `display: block;` by default so they will always stack on top of each other unless otherwise specified through css. SPAN tags are `display: inline;` by default so they would be a better option, in this case, saving you time in code.